# swiftUI - Button Camera in TabBar

Tags: button, swiftui, tabbar

There is a button in the TabBar, this button should open the camera

"Button(action: {...}, label: { ..."

The camera code is written in "CameraView" and "CameraModel" :

```
struct CameraView: View {
    
    @StateObject var camera = CameraModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            
            // Camera preview...
            CameraPreview(camera: camera)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
            
            VStack{
                
                if camera.isTaken{
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: {}, label: {
                            
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath.camera")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.white)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                        })
                        .padding(.trailing,10)
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                HStack{
                    
                    if camera.isTaken{
                        
                        Button(action: {}, label: {
                            Text("Save")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .padding(.vertical,10)
                                .padding(.horizontal,20)
                                .background(Color.white)
                                .clipShape(Capsule())
                        })
                        .padding(.leading)
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    else{
                        
                        Button(action: {camera.isTaken.toggle()}, label: {
                            
                            ZStack{
                                
                                Circle()
                                    .fill(Color.white)
                                    .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                                
                                Circle()
                                    .stroke(Color.white,lineWidth: 2)
                                    .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 75)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            
            camera.Check()
        })
    }
}


class CameraModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var isTaken = false
    
    @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
    
    @Published var alert = false
    
    // since were going to read pic data....
    @Published var output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    
    // preview....
    @Published var preview : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    func Check(){
        
        // first checking camerahas got permission...
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .authorized:
            setUp()
            return
        // Setting Up Session
        case .notDetermined:
            // retusting for permission....
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
                
                if status{
                    self.setUp()
                }
            }
        case .denied:
            self.alert.toggle()
            return
            
        default:
            return
        }
    }
    
    func setUp(){
        
        // setting up camera...
        
        do{
            
            // setting configs...
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
            
            // change for your own...
            
            let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
            
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
            
            // checking and adding to session...
            
            if self.session.canAddInput(input){
                self.session.addInput(input)
            }
            
            // same for output....
            
            if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output){
                self.session.addOutput(self.output)
            }
            
            self.session.commitConfiguration()
        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

// setting view for preview...

struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @ObservedObject var camera : CameraModel
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) ->  UIView {
        
        let view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        camera.preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: camera.session)
        camera.preview.frame = view.frame
        
        // Your Own Properties...
        camera.preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(camera.preview)
        
        // starting session
        camera.session.startRunning()
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

How to call the camera on click Button in TabBar "Button(action: {}, label: {
)"?

Comment: What do you mean by "call the camera"?

Comment: Camera opening...

Comment: Like taking a picture and pausing the preview?

Comment: Pressing the "button" -  opened the camera preview in app

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example of how I did it in the past (after all permissions etc... have been done).
Use your code to do the same.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var image: UIImage?
    @State private var showCamera = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { self.showCamera.toggle() }) {
                Image(systemName: "camera.circle").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
            if image != nil {
                Image(uiImage: image!).resizable().frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            }
        } // this is where it happens
         .sheet(isPresented: $showCamera, onDismiss: {self.showCamera = false}) {
            CameraViewController(photo: $image)
        }
    }
}

struct CameraViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var photo: UIImage?
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraViewController>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let vc = UIImagePickerController()
        vc.sourceType = .camera
        vc.delegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
        var parent: CameraViewController
        
        var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
        var capturePhotoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput!
        var theCamera: AVCaptureDevice!
        var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
        
        let photoQualityPrioritizationMode = AVCapturePhotoOutput.QualityPrioritization.speed
        
        init(_ imagePickerController: CameraViewController) {
            self.parent = imagePickerController
        }
        
        // called when a picture has been taken
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
                print("No image found")
                return
            }
            parent.photo = image   // <--- the photo image
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but this method is not suitable unfortunately